# Convert const std::vector<std::string> to const char **

Tags: c++, vector, c++03

I have a function with signature like this:

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    ...
}
```

I want convert vector `args` to `const char **` (just like `argv` in main). How this can be done? We can't actually make a `char **` array because then it (obviously) fails to convert `args[i].c_str()` that is of type `const char *` to `char *`.

The only (ugly) way I can think of is to use `const_cast` to cast from `const char *` to `char *`.

Would anyone suggest more *elegant* way of doing this? I should note I can use only c++03 features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to flatten the array to a single string, or take pointers to each string?

Comment: Why const is a problem? your result (char**) is not a copy?

Comment: @JohnDibling, take pointers to each string.

Comment: Indeed you can't make a `char **` array from the `c_str()` results; but there's nothing stopping you making a `const char **` array from them, which is what you say you want.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, so here's the question _how_ to make `const char **` from `std::vector<std::string>`. Do you know the other way out of that Sebastian suggested?

Comment: @maverik: I'm not sure what you mean. Sebastian's answer is what I'd have suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done without an extra array. A `const char**` means "a pointer to a pointer to const char" - so you need a place where there are actual pointers to char to point to.

So you need to create that array.

```
struct c_str { const char* operator ()(const std::string& s) { return s.c_str(); } };
std::vector<const char*> pointers(args.size());
std::transform(args.begin(), args.end(), pointers.begin(), c_str());
// If you really want to be compatible with argv:
pointers.push_back(0);
// &pointers[0] is what you want now
```

Comment: Note: The `struct c_str` will need to be declared *outside* of the function in C++03. In C++11, it can be inside (of course, then it can also be a Lambda).